# How to get an image to display in a Wordpress template with loop?

Tags: php, loops, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am creating pages in Wordpress that display all posts with a tag the same as the page title (all 'dog' posts for a page named 'dogs' for example. The goal is to be able to quickly create category pages.

The code I have bellow successfully shows the title and text of the post, but I want to also display an image for each post (if the post has any images). 2 questions...

-How to display one image per post with wordpress?

-How to implement the above alongside the text in a loop?

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Category Page Template
 * Description: A Page Template for Categories
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">


                <?php $catname = wp_title('', false); ?>
<?php query_posts("category_name=$catname&showposts=3"); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts("category_name=$catname&numberposts=3&offset=0");
foreach ($posts as $post) : include(loop.php);?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
add_theme_support('post_thumbnails');
add_image_size('homepage-thumbnail',300, 200, true);
```

to your functions.php, you might also want to set image sizes at the same time look into set_post_thumbail_size() and add_image_size() to do that

and in your loop add something like

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()){
  the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumbnail');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 to get the image for post refer to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image), call:

```
wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr)
```

2.to put text in a loop, do something like:

```
<?php
query_posts("category_name=$catname&posts_per_page=3"); 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   the_title();
   the_excerpt();
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```